# Elm: switching from Browser.element to Browser.application - what are the required changes on JS side?

Tags: javascript, elm

The need to manipulate URLs recently arose in my Elm app, so [according to the docs](https://guide.elm-lang.org/webapps/navigation.html) I had to change from a `Browser.element`-based approach to `Browser.application`. This required a few changes including my `view` function which had to be changed to return a record with a `title` and a `body` field.

There is no mention in the guide about updating the initializer JS code and I expected this will break my app because it is still initialized like so:

```
var app = Elm.Main.init({
  node: document.getElementById('elm')
});
```

The app kept working, it didn't brake it! Dumbfounded, I went googling and found [this article](https://korban.net/posts/elm/2018-10-12-elm-guide-missing-part-url-handling-browser.application/#a-note-on-lt-body-gt-) that says "... [other elements in body] just have to appear after the script with Elm.Main.init". I do have some bootstrap-datepicker js lib referenced in a `<script>` tag **before** the elm initialization code!

What's the deal here? I fear I just happen to be lucky with some default behavior. How does `Browser.application` take over the body tag? What is the correct way to initialize a `Browser.application`-based Elm app that also has to include custom javascript in the html body?
Maybe the elm guide should be updated to include such info as well.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this works is because the Elm initialiser checks for the records it needs and ignores any others. It's the same as if you passed in:

```
var app = Elm.Main.init({
  foobar: null
});
```

(This is because JS is not type-checked like Elm, so objects can have fairly arbitrary shapes)

AFAIK you might need the `flags` key.